# On click suggestions don't replace the good value in text box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Basically, I have a search box that suggests results from a database as user types. It looks like this : 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKAhs.jpg)
.
I use ajax in a file to make a live search as user types :

```
<input name="estab" id="estab" type="text" class="estab" />
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
            $("#estab").on("input", function(){
                $estab = $("#estab").val();
                if ($estab.length > 0){ 
                    $('#result').show();
                    $.get("res.php", {"estab":$estab},function($data){
                        $("#result").html($data);
                })
            }
            });
<script>
```

Then in another file (res.php) I have a sql request and I display results. I also have my 'onclick' function to replace suggestion in text box :

```
while($result=$data->fetch_assoc()){
    $sortie[] = $result['school'];
}
$sortie2=array_unique($sortie);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($sortie2 as $value){

    echo "<script>
            function fill(){
            document.getElementById('estab').value = '$value';
            $('#result').hide();
            }
        </script>";
    echo "<li onclick='fill()'><b>$value</b></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

My problem is : when i click on any of the suggestion, it is always the last option that is replaced in the text box, in this case "University of Washington".

I have been trying to solve that problem for 2 days now and I can't find the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Found the solution, if someone is interested, here's what I did in res.php:

```
while($result=$data->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<li onclick='fill("<?php echo $result['school']; ?>")'><?php echo $result['school'];?></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

and in the first file :

```
<script>

        function fill(val){
            $('#estab').val(val);
            $('#result').hide();
        }
            $("#estab").on("input", function(){
                $estab = $("#estab").val();
                if ($estab.length > 0){ 
                    $('#result').show();
                    $.get("res.php", {"estab":$estab},function($data){
                        $("#result").html($data);
                })
            }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: write the javascript function outside the forloop.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, which it looks like in the <script> tag above, why not just use jQuery to assign the click event to the <li> tags instead of using the onclick attribute? That's not best practice anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the onclick method here. I would use jQuery to assign the events to your list items. But if you must, in your onclick method, try passing this.value like so:

```
<li onclick="fill(this.value)"><b>$value</b></li>
```

Then your fill() method could be something like so:

```
function fill(val){
    $('#estab').val(val);
    $('#result').hide();
}
```

EDIT: You are mixing plain JavaScript and jQuery code. I replaced your plain JS line with the jQuery equivalent.

Also, if you are adding the fill() method in the same loop that adds the LIs, then you are adding multiple fill methods, which is incorrect. Just add it once in the same script tag like below.

```
<script>
     function fill(val){
         $('#estab').val(val);
         $('#result').hide();
     }

    $("#estab").on("input", function(){
            $estab = $("#estab").val();
            if ($estab.length > 0){ 
                $('#result').show();
                $.get("res.php", {"estab":$estab},function($data){
                    $("#result").html($data);
            })
        }
    });
<script>
```

Comment: He post the fill method as `echo`

Comment: Updated my answer with the original fill() method with corrections.

Comment: As you pointed out, i was using jquery and plain js in the same function which was weird so i fixed that. With your method, I always get 0 in the text box when i click any of the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script>
        function fill(newValue){
        document.getElementById('estab').value = '" + newValue + "'" + ;
      "  $('#result').hide();
        }
    </script>";

echo '<ul>';
foreach($sortie2 as $value){
    echo "<li onclick='fill($value)'><b>$value</b></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I feel like there's a problem with 'fill($value)' because when i do this, my javascript function is not triggered

Comment: check the source code of your result page and see if you see something like `fill('university Washington')`